# Where to place the authentication logic in Laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have used this tutorial for creating my user login in Laravel: [Laravel Authentication Essentials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msEwmVZ4wp4). So I have a `SessionController` that contains the methods `create`, `store` and `destroy`, for showing the form, logging in and out respectively.

But there is no model in this tutorial, the validation and `Auth::attempt` is in the controller. And that doesn't feel right. I can not create a `Session` model, since the `Session` class already exists.

Should I put the login/out logic in the `User` model, or is there another way to do this that complies with the MVC architectural pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember (or know) that you can change everything in Laravel. If you need a Session model using a sessions table, go to app/config/session.php and change the Laravel sessions table to laravel_sessions:

```
'table' => 'laravel_sessions',
```

People are doing things differently these days, methods are improving on a daily basis and the way you do your code must be confortable to you. If you feel it is not right the way you are seeing people doing it, change it, Laravel give you the power to change and do things your way. And if you feel you just found a better way of doing it, share it.

This is a 2013 video and today Jeffrey is doing authentication in a completly different way. Sign up for a [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) account and take the full [Build a Larabook](https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-laravel-app-from-scratch) video series to see how he's doing it now.

There's no Session model in this tutorial because he's not storing sessions (successful logins) in a sessions table.

In the tutorial he never touches the User model, so there is no login in the user model. The only thing he's using to do authentication is `Auth::attempt()`, a Laravel facade method which uses internally the user model **(M)**, to find a user and check if the password matches. He's working with a Session **controller** **(C)** and everything related to login (or sign in) and showing login views **(V)** is done inside that particular controller.

If it is easier to you, you can rename SessionsController to LoginController, I, myself, don't really like the Sessions name for login, but that's a matter of taste not code correctness.

That being said I don't see an MVC (or whatever name people like to call it this week) problem in that  video.

**EDIT** Answering the comment:

The purpose of the model is towards data, no data, no model. In the context of Laravel and a database management system, yes, no table, no model. In the context, for instance, of a client-server API, your server API (Laravel, Rails...) will provide data for your client model (Angular, EmberJS...), so, there will be no table directly related to the client model, but still a model.

But in that particular case you are accessing a model, the user model, via a service, the Authentication service.

Comment: Another great answer, thank you Antonio :) So the purpose of the model is towards a database table, no table no model? (in a nutshell) I've been leaning towards signing up with Laracasts for some time now, great resource!